# Value of `#$` when loading elisp files

Tags: load, profiler

What is the value of `#$` when loading a file?

`package.el` generates files like:

```
;;; anzu-autoloads.el --- automatically extracted autoloads
;;
;;; Code:
(add-to-list 'load-path 
    (directory-file-name (or (file-name-directory #$) 
                             (car load-path))))
```

Context: I'm trying to profile files loaded by intercepting calls to `load`. https://github.com/jschaf/esup/issues/53